# Physiological function of CFTR gene product?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, homework, medicine

I just need a clarification.

If I am to talk about the physiological function of the CFTR gene product? Then what should I do research and talk about?

The only physiological function that I can think of is the control of the thickness of mucus.

Is there any other ones?

On top of that, if i am to search for research paper for this topic. Do I just search for comparative study that compare the gene product in normal individuals and CF individuals in terms of mucus thickness?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cystic_fibrosis_transmembrane_conductance_regulator) on CFTR? It's usually a good start and has plenty of references.

Comment: I did. But I don't think it is good enough.

Comment: Have you read the answers of this: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23557/functions-of-the-cftr-gene ?
E.g. it helps by absorbing salt after sweating.